# loading assets infinitely on a nginx for nodejs application whose resources are compiled with webpack

Tags: node.js, nginx, webpack, vuejs2, mime-types

I try to put a nodejs application in production using a nginx server when I test locally everything works fine but when I put on line I have an infinite load of some particular assets

here is my nodejs configuration file

```
upstream beauteadom_me {
    server localhost:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name beauteadom.me www.beauteadom.me;
    location ~ /\.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
    }
        root /var/www/beauteadom.me;
    location / {
        return 301 https://www.beauteadom.me$request_uri;

    }


}

server {

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
http2_push_preload off;


    server_name www.beauteadom.me;
    root /var/www/beauteadom.me;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/beauteadom.me.log notice;
    access_log off;

    location / {
        http2_push_preload off;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        proxy_pass http://beauteadom_me;
    }

    location /websocket/ {
        proxy_pass http://beauteadom_me;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location ~* \.(html|css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg|eot|woff|ttf)$ {
         expires max;
         proxy_pass http://beauteadom_me;
    }
    location ~ /\. { deny all; }

gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_min_length 1000;
gzip_comp_level  2;
gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";


access_log off;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;

open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
open_file_cache_valid 30s;
open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
open_file_cache_errors on;

pagespeed on;

pagespeed FetchHttps enable,allow_self_signed;
pagespeed FileCachePath /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache;
pagespeed RewriteLevel OptimizeForBandwidth;
location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" {
  add_header "" "";
}
location ~ "^/pagespeed_static/" { }
location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon$" { }

}
```

here's what i get in my chrome browser console
[image]
I think it's definitely one to one nginx security setting given that i do not have this problem locally
I already googling too much please I need your help. thank you in advance

Comment: Is that long path OK ? Looks like a redirect issue. `assets/js` redirecting it repeatedly.

Comment: In production on a local machine I do not have this problem but on the server nginx online before its loop on these assets that I do not use in this page. I think it's because nginx asks the browser to preload some assets

Comment: this path is invalid the root /assets/icon is not good and the browser loops by adding each time asstes /js/

Comment: Can you add your node code as well, it's likely a problem there.

Comment: what part of my code seen that the application is quite complex with a lot of file

Comment: I found out what's the problem there was a gif that I try to load into one of my files seen and that was not present on the server